# how to get row click event in Datagrid?

Tags: vb.net

Here is the situation:-

```
I binded an Id to a column in a datagrid.
and now i want to pass that Id to row click event of this Datagrid.

1.What is the row click event of Datagrid?

2.How to pass this Id to the event?
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With this example you can capture the row index and the column index

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseClick(sender As [Object], e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs)

    Dim cellInformation As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    cellInformation.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "ColumnIndex", e.ColumnIndex)
    cellInformation.AppendLine()
    cellInformation.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "RowIndex", e.RowIndex)
    cellInformation.AppendLine()
    MessageBox.Show(cellInformation.ToString(), "CellMouseClick Event")
End Sub
```

Comment: This event is not supported.Giving error - Type 'DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs' is not defined.